# GwtQuery for a "click" event it also does trigger on hover event (sometimes)

Tags: java, jquery, gwt, gwtquery, gquery

GwtQuery for a "click" event it also does trigger on hover (sometimes), why is that?

```
   $("html").bind("click", new com.google.gwt.query.client.Function() {
        @Override
        public boolean f(com.google.gwt.user.client.Event e) {
            $(".hopscotch-bubble").fadeOut(new com.google.gwt.query.client.Function() {
                @Override
                public void f() {
                    JSNIHelper.infoNotify("INFO", "Fade out method invoked.");
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check that other parts of your code are ok, gwtquery bind only sets the event you specify. Could you post a test or code fragment which demonstrates the wrong behaviour?. I have tested this code and works as expected (had to change JSNIHelper by log)

Comment: I had to put this code fragment in a @Singleton class

Comment: Of course you should not add the same binding to the same element multiple times, because you will fire the handler many times.

Comment: This bind method is called during onStart() of the Hopscotch tour, so it could have been called many times. This is because this ".hopscotch-bubble" is only available when the tour bubble is shown; or is it safe to bind to class even its not actively there yet?

Comment: anyhow, during the onEnd() and onClose() of the tour, the $("html").unbind("click"); is called, so it that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked this question two times in same context :)

- [GwtQuery for a “click” event it also does trigger on hover event (sometimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216459/gwtquery-for-a-click-event-it-also-does-trigger-on-hover-event-sometimes)
- [Click event being fired even not clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217630/click-event-being-fired-even-not-clicking/22218166#22218166)

Please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217630/click-event-being-fired-even-not-clicking/22218166#22218166). It will definitely solve your problem.