# Click event being fired even not clicking

Tags: java, gwt

I have this code which fires even if I don't click on anything on the page, just hovering over the page this will trigger:

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent event) {
                switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
                    case Event.ONCLICK:
                        $(".hopscotch-bubble").fadeOut(new com.google.gwt.query.client.Function() {
                            @Override
                            public void f() {
                                JSNIHelper.infoNotify("INFO", "Fade out method invoked!");
                            }
                        });

                }
            }
        });
```

I am not entirely sure why this happens, what could be the reason?

Comment: Just to be clear - the `infoNotify()` triggers or `onPreviewNativeEvent()`?

Comment: Its working fine for me. Please mention imports also or try my answer.

Comment: Can't say, maybe the hopscotch library relies on the trig of click events for the navigation. I'd give http://eemi2010.github.io/gwt-tour/ a shot (it's a wrapper though, so probably you will have the same issue).

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [ClickHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ClickHandler.html) on the Root Panel itself that will be called when a native click event is fired anywhere on the page.

#### Sample code:

```
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

RootPanel.get().addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Click");
        
    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());
```